# Combine mutliple JSON files without overwriting any data (Using JS/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple JSON files containing a series of questions and multiple choice answers. I have a file for each of a series of topics. I want to be able to select from a list a number of these topics and then read each of the associated files from the selected topics and combine them to make a quiz. When I try to merge JSON files, the last merged file overwrites whatever was there before, since each file has the same structure:

```
{
    "questions": [{
        "question": "What is the supreme law of the land?",
        "answers": [
            "The Constitution",
            "The Declaration of Independence",
            "The Bill of Rights",
            "None of the above"
        ],
        "correct_answer": "0"
    }, {
        "question": "What does the Constitution do?",
        "answers": [
            "Sets up the government",
            "Gives the President complete power",
            "Protects the rights of only the President and Congress",
            "None of the above"
        ],
        "correct_answer": "0"
    }]
}
```

So, I may need to combine 10 such files and then do something simple like pass the result to my quiz processing code.
I have been trying to use multiple $.getJSON("quiz1",function(json1){ quizquestions1 = json1; }); statements, but i'm having a brain ft on how I can just add all of the 'question' elements into one JSON file before processing my quiz.
I know it's a simple solution, but I've been banging my head on the wall for a while now and just need a pointer in the right direction!!
Thanks everyone!

Comment: did you have thought to group the questions and answers in one JSON reply (with other words, at the server) ? The code development would be more easier i think.